# No Bootable Device - Occasional error after installing Windows 10 to new SSD

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd

Whenever I start my computer I get this error message:

[image: No bootable device]

However to fix it I just need to restart my computer and I get a screen that looks like this:

[image: Choose an operating system]

When I select the SSD everything boots up fine but I feel like something isn't quite right with my configuration for this error message to show. Any idea what is happening?

Just installed the SSD (M.2) last week, haven't had any issues with it so far other than this error message. Computer is an Acer Aspire V17 Nitro (VN7-791G), bios is set to boot using EUFI with the SSD second after "Boot Manager". SSD is a Samsung 850 EVO Series 250GB. Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on this forum: http://community.acer.com/t5/V-and-VN-Series/No-Bootable-Device-when-system-starts-After-shut-down-cold-boot/m-p/389512#M5857

If Windows finds an existing EFI partition on another drive it won't install a new EFI partition. So when I was installing my SSD it didn't actually install an EFI partition on the SSD. To get around this you need to unplug your other drives (or disable in BIOS) so that Windows creates a new EFI partition.